# How to have a domain redirect to a subdirectory?

Tags: url, dns, url-routing

Using only DNS, how can I have `http://www.example.com/` either redirect or resolve to `http://www.anotherdomain.com/example` ?

**UPDATE:**

Since it's been mentioned below that DNS cannot be used, what's the next best alternative (minimize load on server and provides the fastest redirect experience for the user)  ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. DNS doesn't handle URLs, just maps names to IPs.

URLs aren't part of DNS, only domain names are.

Comment: Okay, so since I can't use DNS - what's the next best alternative (minimize load on server and provides the fastest redirect experience for the user)  ?

Comment: If you are using apache, set up a permanent redirect on example.com:

Redirect permanent / http://www.anotherdomain.com/example

Docs are at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

Other http servers have other ways to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Tim Howland said, you can't. You need to use something like the URL rewrite module for Apache or a redirect page (both on example.com).